# SharePoint O365 Calendar size limits

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

I am running up against size limitations within a single calendar. I am having to sometimes create an additional calendar to hold overflow data, or to delete old data from my calendar...is there a way I can increase the amount of data that I can hold in a single calendar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to increase the amount of data that a single calendar can hold?

What’s the error you encounter when you use the calendar?

There is a list view threshold limit which is 5000, there is no method to increase the limit in SharePoint Online.

In fact, you can set some filters or split the events to different views.

Comment: If it helps, you can mark it as answer.